# Resample pandas dataframe by two columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe that describes arrivals at stations. It has two columns: time and station id.

Example:

```
                   time     id
0   2019-10-31 23:59:36     22
1   2019-10-31 23:58:23     260
2   2019-10-31 23:54:55     82
3   2019-10-31 23:54:46     82
4   2019-10-31 23:54:42     21
```

I would like to resample this into five minute blocks, which shows the number of arrivals at the station in the time-block that starts at the time, so it should look like this:

```
                   time     id     arrivals
0   2019-10-31 23:55:00     22     1
1   2019-10-31 23:50:00     22     5
2   2019-10-31 23:55:00     82     0
3   2019-10-31 23:25:00     82     325
4   2019-10-31 23:21:00     21     1
```

How could I use some high performance function to achieve this?
[pandas.DataFrame.resample](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) does not seem to be a possibility, since it requires the index to be a timestamp, and in this case several rows can have the same time.

Comment: How do you get "arrivals"? And how does id 260 become 82 in your output? Also "time" in your output is not 5min intervals.

Comment: The "arrivals"-collumn is basically the number of rows that match the condition. If there are five rows describing arrivals at station 22 in the five minute period 2019-10-31 23:50:00 to 2019-10-31 23:54:59, the result is one line: `2019-10-31 23:50:00     22     5`. 

So id 260 does not 'become' 82 like you said - my example result just does not include the result for 260.

Answer (score 1):

```
df.groupby(['id',pd.Grouper(key='time', freq='5min')])\
    .size()\
    .to_frame('arrivals')\
    .reset_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a horrible solution (couldn't find a better one at the moment), but it more or less gets you where you want:

```
df.groupby("id").resample("5min", on="time").count()[["id"]].swaplevel(0, 1, axis=0).sort_index(axis=0).set_axis(["arrivals"], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.resample.html?highlight=resample#pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.resample):

```
>>> df.set_index("time").groupby("id").resample("5min").count()
                         id
id  time                   
21  2019-10-31 23:50:00   1
22  2019-10-31 23:55:00   1
82  2019-10-31 23:50:00   2
260 2019-10-31 23:55:00   1
```